# How do I stop the VSCode code completion popup from activating on the space-bar key

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I hit the space bar, I want a space and no code completion, no suggestions, just a space. I'm tired of backspacing through #endregion. I'm annoyed by not being able to space-upArrow or space-downArrow and various other things. I like more spaces in my code than most people do, I suppose, but with 40 years of coding behind me, I'm not likely to change anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set these two settings in your settings.json (Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) via the command palette)

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
```

Comment: This is a fail. I just want to turn it off for a space character, this turns it off for way more than that.

Comment: This doesn't work either:// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    { "key": "space", "command": "-notification.toggle" }
]